# G++ floating point precision

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, g++

I have these lines in a C++ program,

```
auto f = log (FLT_MAX / 4);
printf("%e", f);
cout << f;
```

The `printf` result is 8.733654e+1, but `cout` gives me 87.3365. I checked the 32-bit hex values, they're respectively 0x3f5f94e0 and 0x3f5f94d9, meaning, there seems to be enough precision to represent the value exactly.

Do you know why `cout` is truncating that floating point value?

Comment: Many values cannot be precisely represented in a floating point value.  `0.1` for example, is a repeating binary pattern in the same way that 1/3 has no exact decimal representation.

Comment: Why are there two, slightly differening, values? That might explain the difference in output (beside the fact the two output routines might have a different precsion set).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with g++.

What you should do is this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10+1) << f;
```

You can also use `long double` instead of `double` to get the maximum precision available.

---

### Documentation

- [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)
- [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/)

Comment: ISTM that you sometimes get downvotes that are not explicable.I guess anyone with a little reputation has had them.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know why cout is truncating that floating point value?

Because the default precision C++ streams are set to is 6.

You can change the precision with [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).